# Microsoft Azure VM image completely same as Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Can I have an image on Azure VM that has completely same set of softwares installed on it as on Azure Pipeline?

I'm debugging a build script of a Windows native application on Azure Pipeline pool, whose vmImage is `windows-2019`.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft hosted agents use a Standard_DS2_V2 windows-2019 image.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#hardware

Image spec: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/dv2-dsv2-series#dsv2-series

Comment: In the software section of the page, I found a link to a github page here.
  https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/win/Windows2019-Readme.md

I maybe became a little close to the solution. However, I cannot find how to make a VM that has the same softwares and same setup paths.
I tried to create a VM instance of Standard DS1v2 but Visual Studio is not installed on the VM.